# Python Server Sending Email

Tags: python, sockets, email

So I have a server that connects to a client.  The client requests an email to be sent by the server and the server sends the email.  The email is successfully sent but when the server responds to the email sent, it times out.

```
emailsender = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
emailsender.ehlo()
emailsender.starttls()
        try:

           emailsender.sendmail(gmailaccount,email,emailmsg)

           emailsender.quit

        except:
           serverSocket.sendto('Unable to find slots',address)
           continue

serverSocket.sendto('Successfully booked meeting',address)
```

The email sender works because I was able to recieve the email.  If I don't send the email the client recieves the serverSocket but if the email is sent, the client doesn't recieve the serverSocket.  I think I figured out the problem because when the email is sent, the client recieves that.  How can i prevent that from happenning? Here is the Client side

```
try:
   clientSocket.sendto(msg(host,port))
   response,address = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
except:
   print 'Timed out'
```

Comment: I don't understand; can you repeat the bit where you explain all about the things? What times out, where, with what message? What do you mean "the client does/doesn't receive the serverSocket"? Where does serverSocket come from? What do you mean "emailsender blocking the serverSocket" - blocking it from doing what? "When the email is sent the client receives that, how can I prevent that from happening?" the client receives what, prevent what from happening?

Comment: So the client sends the msg to the server to send the email.  The server sends the email but when it does (I believe) that the client recvs that too causing the error.  Therefore is it possible for the client to not do that?

Comment: Well I figured a loop hole around it where i slept the client for 10 seconds before recving msg from server.  However if there is any other solutions, I would like to know thank you.

Comment: Are these TCP or UDP sockets? Have you used `socket.settimeout()`? Is there a bug in your client code where there should be a comma after `msg`? Can you post more code because I don't think what you've posted shows a major problem?

Comment: They are UDP sockets.  Its just that the client recvs the email msg sent by the server causing the exception to be thrown.  I was able to solve it but sleeping it for 3 seconds and than start recv after the email msg was sent.

Comment: Do you actually mean the client gets the email content? Then you have something wired up wrongly in code you haven't posted. Do you mean the client receive call times out because the email takes too long to send? Have you tried `clientSocket.settimeout()` to set a longer timeout?

Comment: The client isnt suppose to get the email content lol.  the timeout is set to 1.  Its just that the client throws the except when the Server sends the email so i slept the client for 3 seconds and it worked.  what would setting the timeout to a longer period do?

Comment: When you call recvfrom() the client waits for 1 second and then throws the timeout error. If you call `clientSocket.settimeout(20)` then call recvfrom(), it will wait 20 seconds before throwing the timeout error. It's like sleeping your code, except the socket will return as soon as the data comes in, and sleep never will, it always waits for the whole sleep time.